# Error Ant Build/deploy to websphere 7.0

Tags: ant, websphere

Hi I'm trying to build/deploy war to websphere process server 7.0. and I run on windows environment.....

I use http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2008/08/ant-automated-deployment-to-websphere.html as my reference. and http://illegalargumentexception.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/code/java/WebSphereAntFiles/ as my sample code to deployed.

this is my buil.properies is ?

```
#build properties
mywebappear=D:/data/code/WebSphereAntFiles/scripts/test/mywebappEAR.ear



#WAS6 install directory
was_home=C:/IBM/WID7_WTE/runtimes/bi_v7
#server name (see cell/node/server; e.g. "server1")
was_server=server1
#user + password; for use when security is enabled
was_user=admin
was_password=admin
#stops scripts on problem
was_failonerror=true
#virtual host
was_virtualhost=default_host

#Absolute path to EAR file
#was_ear=fooEAR.ear

#Name of the enterprise application
#was_appname=fooEAR
```

this is my console while I trying to build with ws_ant.bat

```
[wsDefaultBindings] mywebapp.war
[wsDefaultBindings]   <virtual-host> --> default_host
[wsDefaultBindings]
[wsDefaultBindings] ------------------------


[wsDefaultBindings] Saving EAR File to directory
[wsDefaultBindings] Saved EAR File to directory Successfully

test_wsStartServer:

WAS_wsStartServer:

depCheck:

depCheck:
[startServer] ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
[startServer]            C:\IBM\WID7_WTE\runtimes\bi_v7\profiles\qwps\logs\server1\startServer.log
[startServer] ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the qwps profile
[startServer] ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
[startServer] ADMU3028I: Conflict detected on port 8880.  Likely causes: a) An instance of
[startServer]            the server server1 is already running  b) some other process is
[startServer]            using port 8880
[startServer] ADMU3027E: An instance of the server may already be running: server1
[startServer] ADMU0111E: Program exiting with error:
[startServer]            com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMU3027E: An
[startServer]            instance of the server may already be running: server1
[startServer] ADMU1211I: To obtain a full trace of the failure, use the -trace option.
[startServer] ADMU0211I: Error details may be seen in the file:
[startServer]            C:/IBM/WID7_WTE/runtimes/bi_v7/profiles/qwps\logs\server1\startServer.log

BUILD FAILED
D:\data\code\WebSphereAntFiles\scripts\test\build.xml:68: The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\data\code\WebSphereAntFiles\scripts\was\wsStartServer.xml:49: Java returned: -1
```

Comment: The error is not in the build (as mentioned by McDowell. The EAR was successfully deployed to the server as seen in these lines


[wsDefaultBindings] Saving EAR File to directory
[wsDefaultBindings] Saved EAR File to directory Successfully

Why does the build process try to start the server? If you use a script to build and install an application to the server, you are already connected to a running server (you are on a single server environment).  

You don't need the start server in your build scripts. Remove that and work with either the console or the logs to see if your app is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[startServer] ADMU3028I: Conflict detected on port 8880.  Likely causes: a) An instance of
[startServer]            the server server1 is already running  b) some other process is
[startServer]            using port 8880
```

I am guessing that you have already started your server. [com.ibm.websphere.ant.tasks.StartServer](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wbpmcore.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/ant/tasks/package-summary.html) will fail to start the server if it is already running.

Either stop calling this task or stop your server before running the script.

Comment: thanks alot sir ..., I usually start the server while I want to deploy the web application. 

I've try your script, so I want to deploy, I must uninstall the application, and re install the application. I there any trick, I just want to update the application without uninstall and deploy again ?
thanks

Comment: @adisembiring - you can probably do that with the `wsadmin` Ant task (see the WAS Infocenter).