# Websphere Eclipse plug-in and Ant dev environment setup

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, websphere, development-environment

We use Eclipse to develop and Websphere 7.0 to run our code. We use a plugin for Eclipse which allows you run run a copy of WAS locally and integrated with Eclipse. This works but it's not great. Each time I have to make a change I have to run my Ant script (5 mins.) then do my install into WAS and restart the app in WAS (another 5 mins). This is not efficient (actually it's downright annoying!)

What's the best setup Websphere allows, ignoring for a min what is easy to do etc. I want to know what to aim for. Obviously I would love to be able to save in eclipse then go to my browser and refresh the screen, am I mad?

I have looked at this about [using Websphere's native Ant, and it is one avenue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748648/error-ant-build-deploy-to-websphere-7-0) but I'm sure there's better.

Can I use jpda like I do when starting Tomcat and develop directly in the code? I will still need Ant when doing a full re-build as I have some Java file generation to do but for the in-process builds???

Thanks-in-advance for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not just one straightforward single best answer as it depends a lot on the application you are doing.

If you rely on ant to make the build and that takes five minutes for any update you do then it may be hard to get away from that. You may not have to do it like that, you may be able to do incremental compilations (only compiling the updated classes) and that should be a lot quicker (but since I don't know anything about your application it is hard for me to tell you that this is a way forward for you). The updates you make in WAS and if that requires a total restart of the application depends on many different factors.

If I update only a jsp file it usually does not require a full application restart, but if you start to update the classes and definitely when you update your web.xml or something like that, a full restart of the application may be required.

The time it takes for you to restart your application depends a lot on what actions your application will perform when you start it up. If you have an application that takes five minutes to start up, then every restart will cost a lot. Is there something you can do to reduce the restart time in certain configurations? Can you divide your application into separate deployables to reduce the startup time for each individual application?

It all depends on your needs and requirements.

We used to have long startup times for our local servers, but since we had upgraded disks (SSD-disks) and enough memory the server startup time has been reduced by 80-90%.